# jQuery and prototype compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm trying to combine several libraries - some of them rely on prototype.js, and some on jQuery.

Both groups of libraries use the "$", as respectively defined by prototype and jQuery.

Is there a way for me to make sure that each set of libraries refers to the correct $? I would like to be able to call functions from both sets of libraries in my code.

Comment: would http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using closures:

```
(function($) {
    //jQuery stuff
      $('.elem') // $ refers to jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Otherwise use jQuery noConflict:

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
// document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

To expand on this, you can use something like 'j' for the jQuery stuff and keep the dollar sign for prototype:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

Comment: that doesn't help me when using libraries that rely on jquery.

Comment: I think you can just use a closure to specify whether the $ is meant for prototype or jQuery. I edited my answer.

Comment: this brings me partway to a solution, and helped me find the crux of my problem -> some of the prototype based libraries are calling functions from inside of the jQuery based libraries. I don't think that what I want to do, is doable (without editing the libraries in question). Thanks!

Comment: You can just use something other than the $ to reference the jQuery object and leave the dollar sign for prototype. See above.